# How to make migrations only one app inside project using django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, migration, django-migrations

I have the follow project structure:

```
MyProject
|--myBaseApp
|  |--migrations
|  |--__init__.py
|  |--models.py
|  |...
|--myClientApp
|  |--migrations
|  |--__init__.py
|  |--models.py
|  |...
|--myProject
|  |--__init__.py
|  |--settings.py
|  |--urls.py
|  |...
|--manage.py
|...
```

I can import to `myClientApp/models.py` the `models.py` from `myBaseApp`, but when I use the commands on terminal mode:

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate myClienteApp
```

The Django creates, on data base, all tables from `models.py`, both `myClienApp/models.py` and `myBaseApp/models.py`. I'd like to make migrate only the `models.py` from `myClienApp/models.py`. It's possible? Or do I need to create other project?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to make migrations only within one app use,

```
python manage.py makemigrations <app_name>
```

If you want to run migrations only within one app use,

```
python manage.py migrate <app_name>
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like this is the first migration -- Django will migrate the stuff from the myBaseApp if so

You can try to run a specific migration instead i.e.:

`./manage.py migrate myapp 0005_migration_to_run`

Comment: It's actually sufficient to only use the migration *number* when targeting a specific migration, e.g. `./manage.py migrate myapp 0005`. Information on the subject: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/migrations/#reversing-migrations

Answer (score 0):

In addition to other answers, you can make migrations for multiple specific apps by specifying them as shown below:

```
python manage.py makemigrations app1 app2
```

And, you can migrate for only one specific app by specifying it as shown below:

```
python manage.py migrate app1
```

But, you cannot migrate for multiple specific apps by specifying them as shown below:

```
python manage.py migrate app1 app2
```

Then, there is the error below:

> CommandError: Cannot find a migration matching 'app2' from app 'app1'.